# Negative surface gravity and temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, gravity, temperature, event-horizon

Is it possible to have negative surface gravity $\kappa$? Also, since $T=\frac{\kappa}{2\pi}$ then if you have a negative surface gravity then that implies negative temperature too right?

Answer (score 1):

If you time reverse a black hole you get a white hole, and white holes do indeed have a negative surface gravity.

However the physical relevance of this is debatable since there is no process known that could form a white hole. It is an interesting question whether a white hole has a Hawking temperature. People have explored this, for example see [Hawking Radiation in the Spacetime of White Holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09625), Kimet Jusufi, Gen. Relativ. Gravit. 50, 84 (2018). Also a question on this site [Why are white holes the same thing as black holes in quantum gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33254/why-are-white-holes-the-same-thing-as-black-holes-in-quantum-gravity) However in the absence of a proper theory of quantum gravity I think we should regard this as rather speculative.

Comment: In what sense do white holes have negative surface gravity? Time reversal doesn't change the direction of gravity.